# Parameters for BSL Package in R

Tags: r, line, statistics, soil

I am using the landsat BSL (Bare Soil Line) package from R https://rdrr.io/cran/landsat/man/BSL.html, and I am wondering why the code sample is using llimit 0.005 and not 0.01:

> BSL(band3, band4, method = "quantile", ulimit = 0.99, llimit = 0.005)

Source code is at https://rdrr.io/cran/landsat/src/R/BSL.R

I looked at the code and documentation, and documentation says: "The quantile method takes the lowest set of points, those with a NIR/red ratio less than the llimit-th quantile." Is there a reason why llimit parameter is set to 0.005 and not 0.01?  Does 0.005 set up a 2 tail region, one at 0.005 and one at 0.99?

I emailed the author of this package but I didn't get a response about this question so I'm hoping someone on GIS SE might know.

Comment: A 0.5% percentile is just the default, if it does not track with your knowledge or literature that is outlining your research, just change it to the lower limit argument to 1% percentile, which is symmetrical with 99%. BTW, this function is from the landsat package. The BSL package is for Bayesian Synthetic Likelihood with Graphical Lasso.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Jeffrey Evans. Yes, I meant the landsat BSL package.